# Log4j: Conditional additivity (or propagate event to root logger based on condition?)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've very simple task: write all events (warn and above) to main log and for certain logger write debug only messages to second log file (warn and above must be logged to main). Sometimes I wish to see debug messages in main log as well (e.g. log4j.logger.com.test=debug)

Besides I must use log4j properties file syntax. I don't understand if additivity (see my last line) can be conditional in that case or should I use complete different approach for the task (which one?).

What I've for now:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %c:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout

log4j.appender.file2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file2.maxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.file2.maxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.file2.File=${catalina.home}/logs/test.log
log4j.appender.file2.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %c:%L - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = debug, file2
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate = false

log4j.logger.com.test=debug
```

Comment: You have log4j2 tagged, but log4j2 doesn't even support log4j.properties, so I don't understand how you expect to use log4j.properties on that. log4j2 only supports json and xml configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at Log4J2 as log4j1.x is no longer actively maintained (and Log4J2 has several other advantages like performance improvements).

A common use case is writing debug and higher (info,warn, error, fatal) to a file for developers and warn and higher (warn, error, fatal) to another file eg for support.

From your description it sounds like you want to *restrict* output to *only* debug level, and exclude info, warn, error and fatal-level messages. This is possible but not as straight-forward as the use case above. 
You probably need to use filters: 
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html
Take a look at the filter documentation, I'll see if I can dig up an example.

Comment: Log4J2 is still in beta. Looking forward to production ready stage (at least RC).

Comment: The next release will be either 2.0 GA or RC1.